# How to install Ubuntu WSL on Windows 11 without a Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

The [Ubuntu WSL page](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) page only links to the [Microsoft store page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6).

The installation of apps from the Microsoft Store requires a Microsoft account on Windows 11.  Is it possible to install Ubuntu in WSL without a Microsoft Account?

Related issue: https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/ubuntu.com/issues/10644

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to get the underlying WSL Ubuntu deployment tool without a Microsoft account.  If your sole reason for not registering one is "I don't want Microsoft to have my information" then you shouldn't be using Windows either, because they do track you there too.

Comment: While I've provided an answer which allows installation without using the Store, just a note that I was able to sign out of the Store and yet still install the Ubuntu distribution in WSL.

Comment: @user535733 Using and installing Ubuntu in WSL is on topic here as it is an official Canonical release. Please see [this Meta answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17935/1165986) from Zanna (mod) -- *"We should not close questions just because they smell ... Windowsy."*

Comment: @user535733 I was not searching an answer to "abuse" MS. But a way to install that software. It could have been a file to download directly on the Ubuntu website, but there is another official way (see the answer to the question)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update*:  Windows 11 and Windows 10 21H2 now include the ability to install some distributions directly from the command-line without a Microsoft Account.

```
wsl --list --online # Or wsl -l -v
```

... to get a list of available distributions to install.

```
wsl --install --distribution Ubuntu
```

... to install Ubuntu directly.

*Older Windows versions:*

From the [Downloading distributions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distributions) section in the Install docs:

> There are some scenarios in which you may not be able (or want) to, install WSL Linux distributions using the Microsoft Store.

Summary -- Just download the package from the link provided on that page, then `Add-AppxPackage` the resulting download:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wslubuntu2004 -OutFile Ubuntu.appx -UseBasicParsing
Add-AppxPackage .\app_name.appx
```

or, from the GUI:

- Download [the Appx package](https://aka.ms/wslubuntu2004) from your browser.
- Open the downloaded `.appx` file.  Windows will will ask if you want to install it.